# Im trying to add redirect url to submit button on email form on landing page

Tags: html, forms

I have a 2 form email and name submit form I'm modifying for ad campaigns. I really like the template I'm working with, only I never received instructions on attaching a url redirect to the submit button on the second part of the form.

Here is the code for the form.

How would I attach my url to the button?

```
<!-- form -->
<!--[if IE 9 | lt IE 9]><label for="name" class="label">Enter Your Full Name Here</label><![endif]-->
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Full Name Here"/>
<!--[if IE 9 | lt IE 9]><label for="email" class="label">Enter a Valid Email Here</label><![endif]-->
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter a Valid Email Here" />
<button type="submit" class="btn-flat">Sign Up To Get Access</button>
<p class="privacy">Your privacy is safe! We will never spam you.</p>
</form><!-- /end form -->
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a URL to your button;

```
<form action="http://www.yourWebsite.com">
    <button type="submit" class="btn-flat">Sign Up To Get Access</button>
</form>
```

Stick your input boxes above the button here this will take you to www.yourWebsite.com when clicked.

Comment: This doesn't work in outlook for desktop